# VS 2015: WPF Project Template with Nuget-Packages

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to create a small WPF Template-Project with a ResourceDictionary, a Window and some NuGet-Packages.
I found this manual: https://shahbhavya47.wordpress.com/2015/03/11/create-visual-studio-project-template-with-pre-installed-nuget-packages-using-vs-sdk/

It is working pretty well, but as soon as I add WPF-UserControls, I get some strange behavior:

1. If I let the XAML-Page Build to "Page", other Classes with Build
   "None" seem to get compiled and fail because I have Textmarks like
   $safeprojectname$ in there
2. Even if I export the Project, the XAML-File and the Code-Behind Class are missing in the VSTemplate File in the TemplateContent-Section
3. If I add the Page and the Code-Behind File manually and rebuild the Template Project, this Files are not shown anywhere in the Project I create with them

Am I doing something horribly wrong on this matter or are there some Guides arround which focus on the Templates with WPF and how they can be used?

Thanks in advance!

Matthias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the steps how I got it working:

1. Created a template project, added Newtonfost.Json package to it and removed the default Class1.cs from the **solution explorer**, **.vstemplate** file and **.csproj** file as described in that manual.
2. Changed `<OutputType>` in the **.csproj** to **WinExe** and the `<RequiredFrameworkVerison>` to 4.0
3. Added the following line to the first `<PropertyGroup>` of the **.csproj** so that VS could recognize the project as WPF application.

```xml
<ProjectTypeGuids>{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

4. Added the following 4 references to the **.csproj** file to make sure it would compile right after creation:

```xml
<Reference Include="System.Xaml">
  <RequiredTargetFramework>4.0</RequiredTargetFramework>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="WindowsBase" />
<Reference Include="PresentationCore" />
<Reference Include="PresentationFramework" />
```

5. Copied the following 4 files from a standard new WPF project: *App.xaml, MainWindow.xaml, App.xaml.cs* and *MainWindow.xaml.cs* into the template project.
6. In the template project set Action to **None** for all 4 files by selecting each one in the **Solution Explorer** and changing Action in the **Properties** window.
7. Added the following `<ItemGroup>` to the **.csproj** file to make sure that the files are marked correctly in the project that is generated from the template:

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <ApplicationDefinition Include="App.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </ApplicationDefinition>
    <Page Include="MainWindow.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </Page>
    <Compile Include="App.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>App.xaml</DependentUpon>
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="MainWindow.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>MainWindow.xaml</DependentUpon>
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>
```

8. Added the corresponding `<ProjectItem>` elements to the **.vstemplate** file:

```xml
  <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="App.xaml">App.xaml</ProjectItem>
  <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="MainWindow.xaml">MainWindow.xaml</ProjectItem>
  <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="App.xaml.cs">App.xaml.cs</ProjectItem>
  <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="MainWindow.xaml.cs">MainWindow.xaml.cs</ProjectItem>
```

The `ReplaceParameters="true"` makes it possible to include Textmarks into any of the 4 added files. I've used `$safeprojectname$` in App.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private string field = "$safeprojectname$";
}
```

and in the MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock>$safeprojectname$</TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

After this, building the template project produced the zip file in the bin/Debug folder which worked as expected, including replacing those `$safeprojectname$` instances in both files.

Just remember, the main goal of the template project is building the template, so, for example, opening *.xaml* files from that project will show *Invalid Markup* in the designer. It's much easier to start with an ordinary WPF project and then copy its files and relevant pieces of **.csproj** file into a template project.

Comment: Man so many thanks, you're not the Hero I deserve, but the one I needed. One question: Would you add the whole Packages Folder with the NuGet-Items in it? Is that good practice?

Comment: No, the wizard seems to be taking care of that when the project is created from the template.

Comment: Ok Thanks, probably some Typo or so on my side

Comment: Meh, sorry, last question: When I add my Icon via
<Icon>M.ico</Icon>

There is no problem, but as soon as I put it into an Subfolder and change the VSTemplate to:
<Icon>Assets\M.ico</Icon>, it gets ignored, but without exception. Is that a bug or so?

Comment: @MatthiasMüller, if you put a file into a folder in your template project then you need to include the folder in the **content** of <ProjectItem> but you should only use the name without the folder inside **TargetFileName** attribute. Or just skip **TargetFileName** altogether. It worked for me both ways.

Comment: Perfect thanks, now I have a very cool WPF template and all are happy